# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') mongo db channel id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

Hey im trying to make a Logger bot and i use Mongo db to save the channel where the logs will be send in. My problem is when i try to save the message content as example it gives me this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')`

If I try to log the channel id (`console.log(logchannel)`) its working fine

[Thats the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Zcp.png)

**This is the code i've tried:**

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    const guilde = await GuildChannel.find({ guild: message.guild.id })
    if (!guilde[0]) return
    const logchannel = guilde[0].channelid.toString()
    message.guild.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(message.content)
})
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the format; 2. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_; 3. SO is not a online comic book (that second image...)

Comment: The error tells you that the cache does not have an element with that id so you first have to fetch that channel to fill the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `data`.

```js
                    client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
                        if (message.author.bot) return;
                        GuildChannel.findOne({ guildId: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
                            if (data) {
                                const logchannel = data.channelid.toString()
                                client.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(`${message}`)
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                    })
```